# Redirecting email script to web page

Tags: php, email, send

I currently have the below email/db script that works fine but the redirect doesn't seem to be working. Instead of redirecting to the url its just showing the blank php page. How can I fix this?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("register", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO register_interest (Name, Email, Message, Website)

VALUES ('$_POST[Name]', '$_POST[Email]', '$_POST[Message]', '$_POST[Website]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
 mysql_close($con);
$to = "email";
$subject = "Interest";
$email = $_POST['Email'] ;
$message = $_POST['Message'] ;
$headers = "From: $email";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;

if ($sent) {
  header("Location: http://www.url.co.uk"); 
  exit();
} else {
  print "We encountered an error sending your email"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your Apache/PHP log files? There are some issues with your code...

Comment: You DEFINITELY should use mysql_real_escape_string on your POST variables before inserting them into the database. AND you should move over to mysqli as the mysql_ functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
if(!$sent){
    print "We encountered an error sending your email";
    exit;
}

header("Location: http://www.url.co.uk");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however it just gives me a blank page of the php page and does not do the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","register");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Email']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Message']);
$website = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Website']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO register_interest (Name, Email, Message, Website)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message', '$website')";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);

$to = "email@address.com";
$subject = "Interest";
$email = $_POST['Email'] ;
$message = $_POST['Message'] ;
$headers = "From: $email\n";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;

if ($sent) {
  header("Location: http://www.url.co.uk"); 
  exit();
} else {
  print "We encountered an error sending your email"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives me an error stating no database selected. Where does this need to be added?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any blank lines before the opening  PHP tags), then the header directive will not work.